# Merge and Sum Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {'A':{'x':1,'y':0,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
```

```
b = {'A':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
```

Given above dictionaries, how can I sum those values and merge into one single dictionary as below?

`{'A':{'x':1,'y':1,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}`

Comment: Sharing your attempt as a [mcve] is a good idea to avoid this being closed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have values as 0s and 1s only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = {'A':{'x':1,'y':0,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
>>> b = {'A':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
>>> (pd.DataFrame(a) + pd.DataFrame(b)).to_dict()
{'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 'B': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}}
```

This is applicable for posted example only.
For more general idea, where you have only `1`s and `0`s to work with:

```
>>> a = {'A':{'x':1,'y':1,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
>>> b = {'A':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':0}, 'B':{'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
>>> (pd.DataFrame(a) + pd.DataFrame(b)).astype(bool).replace({True:1, False:0})
   A  B
x  1  0
y  1  0
z  0  0
>>> (pd.DataFrame(a) + pd.DataFrame(b)).astype(bool).replace({True:1, False:0}).to_dict()
{'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 'B': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}}
```

Or

```
>>> (pd.DataFrame(a) | pd.DataFrame(b)).to_dict()
{'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 'B': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}}
```

For something without importing a library:

```
>>> {out_k:{k:(a[out_k][k] or b[out_k][k]) for k in a[out_k]} for out_k in a}
{'A': {'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 'B': {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict` and `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(Counter)
for dic in [a,b]:
    for k, v in dic.items():
        d[k].update(v)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'A': Counter({'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}),
             'B': Counter({'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0})})
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code:

```
c = {}
c['A'] = a['A'].update(b['A'])
c['B'] = a['B'].update(b['B'])
```

Comment: This isn't actually summing anything as asked.